# file in UTF-8 using ICONV showing ANSI encoding in notepad ++

Tags: unix, character-encoding

I am facing problem with encoding while changing `.csv` file from `“ISO-8859-7 -t UTF-8` using `ICONV` command. It shows me successfully completed but when this converted file I will export and checks in Notepad ++ it shows me `ANSI` encoding even the characters will different but when I changed the encoding to `UTF-8` manually using Notepad ++ then it shows me the correct character strings.

For an example it is coming like `Î’Î™Î“Î›Î‘ ÎŸÎ›Î¥ÎœÎ ÎŸÎ¥ Î‘Î•Î’Î•` converted using `ICONV` command using `ISO-8859-7 -t UTF-8`.

But above is not correct, when I am changing the encoding to `UTF-8` in notepad ++ then it is coming `ΒΙΓΛΑ ΟΛΥΜΠΟΥ ΑΕΒΕ` which is correct.

Can anyone suggest me how i can get rid out from this problem.

Comment: In Notepad++ one can open a file with encoding UTF-8 - one step. If then you see the correct symbols, all is fine. If you want other programs to see the file as UTF-8 CSV, then you have a second problem.

Comment: Thanks Eggen.. it cleared my doubt

Answer (score 0):

Notepad is merely *guessing* what encoding it should open the file in. The file itself doesn't declare anywhere what encoding it's in. Obviously Notepad gets it wrong. So you need to tell it by hand what encoding the file is *actually* in.

If your file looks okay when interpreted as UTF-8, then it's actually UTF-8. Nothing else to do here.

Comment: You could add a UTF-8 BOM to the beginning of the file to disambiguate it. This is usually unnecessary, but some platforms are more broken than others.

Comment: I'd generally refrain from doing that, since it often breaks even more. Only in very specific scenarios, like an internal tool where you know the client is going to and insists on opening the file directly with Excel, or such...